# Make text area not resizeable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, textarea

I'm using a form in Rails with a text area. This is good, except that the text area is resizable by the user. I don't want the user to be able to resize it. How can I do that?

```
<%= form_tag "doit", :id => "doit_form" do -%> 
  Names <br/>
  <%= text_area_tag "names", nil, :rows => 4, :cols => 50 %> <br/>
  Date <br/>
  <%= text_field_tag "date" %> <br/>
  <%= submit_tag "Do it!" %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
textarea { resize: none; }
```

Works with most browsers. Older browsers don't have the handle to resize textarea fields so then it shouldn't be a problem anyway.